# Continue restart on STOP 0xc00002e1 error on Windows Server 2003 domain controller

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003, windows-event-log

Windows Server 2003 server running raid 1.

It have several problem, one of the hard drives failed and lsass.exe crashes with error 0xc00002e1.

I followed this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/0xc00002e1-error-start-domain-controller

But when i process step 11 `ntdsutil "sem d a" go`
error -1022 JET_errDISKOP, DISK IO error occurred.

The server has a lot of capacity, and I doubt that my edb.log is corrupted because I cannot delete or read it.

Eseutil /P for repair and  Eseutil /G was both passed and finished.

Do i need to focus on the edb.log or try to run the eseutil /D for the defragmentation?

Answer (score 0):

If one of the hard drives in your RAID failed, you could have data corruption. You haven't said if you replaced the drive and repaired the RAID volume either.

Your best bet at this point would be to restore from backups, or simply make a new DC and replicate from a working one in your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Use following steps to fix the issue-

-Before making any significant changes, ensure you have a recent backup of the system state and edb file.

-Ensure that your RAID 1 setup is functioning properly. Replace the failed hard drive and confirm that the RAID array is in a healthy state.

-Since you suspect corruption in the edb.log file, use [Eseutil](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/168508-how-to-repair-exchange-databases-with-eseutil-when-and-how) to repair the Exchange database file,

-If still issue not fixed, restore the edb.log file and associated database from a known good backup.

-Also suggest to Reach out to Microsoft Support for assistance

Comment: He's on server 2003, he's not getting vendor support anymore.